# ArrayList<String>の変数を渡したいが、エラーが出る

Tags: java

JAVAで、ArrayListの変数の受け渡し方法について、
ネットで調べたりしているのですが、
下記のreceive(list);の行で、elicpseが赤字で引数の型が違うエラーとします。

どのように記述すれば、list を渡せますでしょうか？

```
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public test ()
{
   list.add("1番目");
   list.add("2番目");

   receive(list);    // eclipsがここで赤字で型が違うと表示する
}

public receive (ArrayList<String> list_test)
{
   for (i = 0; i < list_test.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(list_test.get(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: testとrecieve関数に戻り値の型を指定していないからでは・・・

Answer (score 1):

同じく、具体的には

public **void** test ()

とか

public **void** receive (ArrayList<String> list_test)

とすれば解消されると思います。

Comment: コードを記載する際はコードブロックとしてマークアップするのがよいです。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054 や http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting を参照して下さい。

Comment: @mjy この回答の場合、void を強調表示したいようですが、コードブロック内でもできましたっけ?

Comment: @masm Markdownでは出来ないと思います。どうしても、というのでしたら、`<pre><code>`の中で`<b>`を使う形でしょうか。どの道、太字や着色での強調というのは意外と伝わらないので、まずはコードを正しく表示する事から始めるのがよいと思います。